Can an equilateral triangle be made with 3 identical isosceles trapeziums?
Can an equilateral triangle be made with 3 identical isosceles trapeziums? I can't seem to find an answer to this.

I now found one it's here:http://williamarmstrong.com/brain/traptrisoln.gif

It is possible, but you need to clearly define what you mean by "made", like in the following example:

$T_1$ consists of $AB_2C_2D_2$
$T_2$ consists of $EC_2FG$
$T_3$ consists of $D_2HIF$
The triangle is defined as $T_1 \cup (T_2 \cap T_3)$

We already have this in Wikipedia, under "dodecahedral numbers". Note the division of each face; the trapezoids appear isosceles and congruent if viewed in the direction perpendicular to their respective planes.

By EdPeggJr
